# Why does Gradle run tests twice?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-testing

If I run my tests by the usual way everything is fine.
The problem is when I run tests with help of gradle they are executed twice. I use grandle to separate execution of small and medium tests.

This is the data of gradle console:

```
Executing tasks: [connectedAndroidTest]

Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature.
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preProductionDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkProductionDebugManifest
:app:preProductionDebugAndroidTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preProductionReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preUiTestDebugAndroidTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preUiTestDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preUiTestReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAnimatedVectorDrawable2421Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72421Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportDesign2421Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72421Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCompat2421Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCoreUi2421Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCoreUtils2421Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportFragment2421Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportMediaCompat2421Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42421Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportVectorDrawable2421Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:preparePlDroidsonroidsGifAndroidGifDrawable123Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareProductionDebugDependencies
:app:compileProductionDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileProductionDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateProductionDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateProductionDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateProductionDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeProductionDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processProductionDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:processProductionDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateProductionDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:incrementalProductionDebugJavaCompilationSafeguard UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileProductionDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileProductionDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileProductionDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeProductionDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileProductionDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateProductionDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeProductionDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformClassesWithDexForProductionDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeProductionDebugJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForProductionDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:processProductionDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForProductionDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:validateSigningProductionDebug
:app:packageProductionDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:assembleProductionDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportTestEspressoEspressoContrib222Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportTestEspressoEspressoCore222Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportTestEspressoEspressoIdlingResource222Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportTestEspressoEspressoIntents222Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportTestExposedInstrumentationApiPublish05Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportTestRules05Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportTestRunner05Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportTestUiautomatorUiautomatorV18212Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareProductionDebugAndroidTestDependencies
:app:compileProductionDebugAndroidTestAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:processProductionDebugAndroidTestManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileProductionDebugAndroidTestRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateProductionDebugAndroidTestBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateProductionDebugAndroidTestResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateProductionDebugAndroidTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeProductionDebugAndroidTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processProductionDebugAndroidTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateProductionDebugAndroidTestSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:incrementalProductionDebugAndroidTestJavaCompilationSafeguard UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileProductionDebugAndroidTestJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileProductionDebugAndroidTestNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileProductionDebugAndroidTestSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeProductionDebugAndroidTestShaders UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileProductionDebugAndroidTestShaders UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateProductionDebugAndroidTestAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeProductionDebugAndroidTestAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformClassesWithDexForProductionDebugAndroidTest UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeProductionDebugAndroidTestJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForProductionDebugAndroidTest UP-TO-DATE
:app:processProductionDebugAndroidTestJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForProductionDebugAndroidTest UP-TO-DATE
:app:validateSigningProductionDebugAndroidTest
:app:packageProductionDebugAndroidTest UP-TO-DATE
:app:assembleProductionDebugAndroidTest UP-TO-DATE
:app:connectedProductionDebugAndroidTest
:app:checkUiTestDebugManifest
:app:prepareUiTestDebugDependencies
:app:compileUiTestDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileUiTestDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateUiTestDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateUiTestDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateUiTestDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeUiTestDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processUiTestDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:processUiTestDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateUiTestDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:incrementalUiTestDebugJavaCompilationSafeguard UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileUiTestDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileUiTestDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileUiTestDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeUiTestDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileUiTestDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateUiTestDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeUiTestDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformClassesWithDexForUiTestDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeUiTestDebugJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForUiTestDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:processUiTestDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForUiTestDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:validateSigningUiTestDebug
:app:packageUiTestDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:assembleUiTestDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareUiTestDebugAndroidTestDependencies
:app:compileUiTestDebugAndroidTestAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:processUiTestDebugAndroidTestManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileUiTestDebugAndroidTestRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateUiTestDebugAndroidTestBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateUiTestDebugAndroidTestResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateUiTestDebugAndroidTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeUiTestDebugAndroidTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processUiTestDebugAndroidTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateUiTestDebugAndroidTestSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:incrementalUiTestDebugAndroidTestJavaCompilationSafeguard UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileUiTestDebugAndroidTestJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileUiTestDebugAndroidTestNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileUiTestDebugAndroidTestSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeUiTestDebugAndroidTestShaders UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileUiTestDebugAndroidTestShaders UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateUiTestDebugAndroidTestAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeUiTestDebugAndroidTestAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformClassesWithDexForUiTestDebugAndroidTest UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeUiTestDebugAndroidTestJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForUiTestDebugAndroidTest UP-TO-DATE
:app:processUiTestDebugAndroidTestJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForUiTestDebugAndroidTest UP-TO-DATE
:app:validateSigningUiTestDebugAndroidTest
:app:packageUiTestDebugAndroidTest UP-TO-DATE
:app:assembleUiTestDebugAndroidTest UP-TO-DATE
:app:connectedUiTestDebugAndroidTest
:app:connectedAndroidTest UP-TO-DATE

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 19.84 secs
```

Tests are executing in lines :app:connectedProductionDebugAndroidTest and :app:connectedUiTestDebugAndroidTest.

Why do gradle run the tests twice? And how to avoid it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are executing `connectedAndroidTest`, gradle will automatically run `connected(FlavorName+BuildType)AndroidTest`, looks like you have 2 flavors (Production and UiTest). You probably can just run one of those commands instead of running `connectedAndroidTest`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! As you probably understand I'm absolutely zero in Gradle. I have two flavors: productFlavors {
        production {
            minSdkVersion 15
        }
        uiTest {
            minSdkVersion 18
        }
    }. Thats why gradle ran tests twice.

Answer (score 1):

I only have one flavor `app`, and the command is
`gradlew :app:connectedDebugAndroidTest -Pandroid.testInstrumentationRunnerArguments.annotation=com.hello.work.annotation.Smoke`, but `gradlew` also run testcase twice.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is super dumb, but I forgot I had a phone plugged into my computer, so Gradle was trying to run tests on both my emulator AND the device. So it was running the tests twice.